# Magnetic field and electric field close to small signal audio

Tags: magnetic-fields, inductance

I have built a very compact tube amplifier.

I have a $6$ V AC / $3$A supply powering the vacuum tube heaters.
The 2 wires (positive & return current) are very close to the input.

The input signal is very weak ($40$ mV).

I want to minimize inductive and capacitive coupling to the input signal.

I have read that you could twist the 2 wires toghether to minimize the magnetic field. But by doing so you basically create 2 solenoids wound into each other.

Solenoid has very high inductance and a very wide magnetic field.
To me it seems counter-intuitive to first create a stronger/wider magnetic field, then afterward cancel it.

I am wondering if it's not better to leave the 2 wires straight close to each other (=lowest inductance =lowest magnetic field)?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

twisting the wires is one way to guarantee that they will remain as close to one another as possible, which is required in order to get their fields to cancel.

In filament windings where one side of the winding is connected to chassis ground, the twisted pair allows the grounded wire to act as a shield to the "hot" side, minimizing its ability to radiate any hum.

You might consider heating the filaments with well-filtered DC. This will eliminate any tendency for the filament connections to introduce hum into the circuit.

Comment: Thank you. Why DC is more quiet than ac ? Physics wise.

Comment: a dc field does not vary in time and hence contains no signals or noise. an AC field varies in time and hence contains signals or noise.

Comment: Would it be correct to add that the twistedness of a twisted pair is not twisted enough to add interesting inductance anyway? Your explanation of it as being a reliable way to keep the wires close together is refreshingly straightforward.

Comment: the twistedness allows the grounded line to serve as a partial "shield" of the hot line and thereby reduce hum pickup. Better reduction occurs when the grounded line completely encloses the hot line, which is how shielded cable works.